# How to model an enumeration where one constant "behaves" differently?

Tags: java, enumeration

I have a status label which shows a message with a colored border according to
the current status. The message itself can vary (that is there can be multiple
messages to `ERROR`) but the `CLEAR` status is different, since it should never
display any message.

**Example usage**

```
setStatus(INFORMATION, "There are new cookies in the jar.");
setStatus(ERROR, "You were to slow.");
setStatus(ERROR, "Stop bugging me, you were to slow.");
clearStatus();
```

How can I model this exceptional state `CLEAR`? Should I remove it from the
enumeration? I have included it into the enumeration, since `CLEAR` is a valid
state to be in except that it does not show a message. Yet a client could call:

```
setStatus(CLEAR, "ups, I gave you a message");
```

What other options are there to model a list of values where all but one are of
equal nature?

```
public class StatusLabel {
    public enum Status {
        CLEAR,
        INFORMATION,
        ERROR;
    }

    Status status = Status.CLEAR;

    public void setStatus(final Status status, final String message) {
        assert status != STATUS.CLEAR;
        // set status and a show message
        this.status = status;
    }

    public void clearStatus() {
        // clear message
        status = Status.CLEAR;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would be fine with an `assert` or throwing an exception. Optionally, maybe you may just ensure that if `status` is `CLEAR`, then `getStatus()` always returns `null` (ugly, I know)

Comment: I do not want ugly :-). I have also hoped for a solution at compile time (assert triggers at execution time). Yet thank you.

Comment: At compile time the only thing I can think of would be several classes implementing an interface. The interface defines `getMessage()`; `Information` and `Error` have a constructor that accepts a `String` and `Clear` has the default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I think a special value like `NONE` or even `null` are absoluly ok, it no problem to model different behavior of enum values. You have to consider, each of these values can have it's own class and as such it's own unique behavior.

```
    public class StatusLabel {
        public enum Status {
            NONE {
                public void show(String msg) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("don't show CLEAR!");
                }
            },
            INFORMATION,
            ERROR;
            public void show(String msg) {
                // do what ever needed
            }
        }

        Status status = Status.NONE;

        public void setStatus(final Status status, final String message) {
            status.show(message);
            this.status = status;
        }

        public void clearStatus() {
            // clear message
            status = Status.NONE;
        }

        public Status getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
    }
```

This way the enum value *really* behave different.

Comment: But then different messages cannot be show with the same state, that is `setStatus(ERROR, "foo");` `setStatus(ERROR, "bar");` is not possible.

Comment: What I understand from 'show' is a synchronour, stateless operation like opening an alert box and wait until the user presses 'OK'. You can do this as often as your user might accespt it with a differnt message each time, as it is provided as parameter and it's not saved. In fact it can't be saved in an enum at all. So, what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would put a property on the Status enumeration "displaysMessage". Then you can just ask the Status enum if you should display the message.